# Forward declare typedef pointer to a classs

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I was wondering about this for some time, and I just cant seem to wrap my head around it. Would anyone share some technical details around my question and possible solutions.

What I have:
**A.h**

```
class A {
  typedef A* APtr;
};
```

**Program.h**

```
#include "A.h"

Class Test
{
  A::APtr _aPtr;
};
```

What I am trying to do is to eliminate the need of including header `A.h` in `Program.h` and want to forward declare the type-defined `APtr` from `A.h` with a forward declaration.

Hope I have clarified my question.

Thanks

Comment: You can't. A forward declaration is not sufficient for accessing members. If you use `A*` instead of `A::APtr _aPtr` in `Test` then a forward declaration like `class A;` before the declaration of `Test` will do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any solution to do these typedef in one place, and use it in multiple files ?

Comment: Perhaps solve it through [*traits*](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/442)?

Answer (score 2):

If your only goal is to eliminate `#include A.h` from `Program.h` and you only need pointer access to `A` inside `Program.h`, then it suffices to just forward declare the class, and use the pointer type directly.

#### Program.h

```
class A;

class Test
{
  A* _aPtr;
};
```

As @Swordfish mentioned in the comment under your question, you cannot use a forward declaration to access members inside a class.